# phonegap ios work with voiceover

Tags: ios, cordova, voiceover

I have an app using phonegap. But When I open voiceover function, it read the out the html code for me. For example . It will read "banner png Image". Is there any method that I can use to skip reading div?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your assumption is correct.  I believe it is reading out the file name of the image.  Give it a label of some kind!